# error: promoted argument ‘scalar’ doesn’t match prototype

Tags: c

I am writing a small graphics lib, and am using an older style of C for fun. When using the following build flags, `-pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wall -Werror -Wextra -ansi`, I get told that `error: promoted argument ‘scalar’ doesn’t match prototype` due to the following code

```
Vector2_t Graphics_vec2_scalar_fmul(Vector2_t, float);

Vector2_t Graphics_vec2_scalar_fmul(a, scalar)
    Vector2_t a;
    float scalar;
{
    a.x *= scalar;
    a.y *= scalar;

    return a;
}
```

I would prefer to keep pedantic-errors enabled, along with Werror. I do know that this is happening because no type is specified for the type initially, so the compiler assumes int and then throws the pedantic error. Is there a way to either fix this (without changing the C style) or to get the compiler to ignore it in this instance (without changing the build flags too much)?

Comment: That style of function definition is K&R style.  It should not be used unless you are using a pre 1989 compiler. It is obsolete. Where did you get that from???

Comment: @AviBerger [The C programming language by K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) is still sold ... :-( It's like a Rosetta stone for "anything C-like" today without being anything like modern C.

Comment: _" using an older style of C for fun"_ - Even older compiler will complain. What's the purpose really? "for fun"?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I do have a copy of that on my bookshelf. I wouldn't code that style unless I had no other options. _"for fun"_ ? Maybe that is why my boss from that era had the largest bottle of aspirin I have ever seen in my life in her office.

Comment: @AviBerger :-D You had _a book_? [You were _lucky_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ue7wM0QC5LE)!

Answer (score 4):

You are using obsolescent C.  The non-prototype function definition will no longer be valid in C23; the notation was marked obsolescent in C90.  Granted, you're using C89 or C90 by virtue of the `-ansi` flag, but you should be using `-std=c18` rather than `-ansi`; you should not need to use a standard that is about 35 years old.

Anyway, you wrote:

```c
Vector2_t Graphics_vec2_scalar_fmul(Vector2_t, float);

Vector2_t Graphics_vec2_scalar_fmul(a, scalar)
    Vector2_t a;
    float scalar;
{
    …
}
```

The function definition is using the non-prototype notation, so the `float` argument is treated as if you'd written:

```
Vector2_t Graphics_vec2_scalar_fmul(Vector2_t a, double d_scalar)
{
    float scalar = d_scalar;
    …
}
```

That is, the second argument is expected to be a `double`, but the compiler will convert that to `float` for use inside the function.  The other major difference is that the non-prototype form does not provide a prototype for the function.

Clearly, though, the implied function definition does not match the declared function prototype, hence the error messages you are seeing.

The fix is simple — write the function definition as a prototype:

```
Vector2_t Graphics_vec2_scalar_fmul(Vector2_t a, float scalar)
{
    …
}
```

Alternatively, declare the function like this:

```
Vector2_t Graphics_vec2_scalar_fmul(Vector2_t a, double scalar);
```

and retain the original function definition.  This is inferior to defining the function with the prototype notation, but would work.

There is no virtue in using the non-prototype function definition notation.  There hasn't been for the whole of this millennium.

Comment: I am a bit confused. I thought that the default type for any identifier is "int", and yet you propose that "double" is implied in this particular case. Will you please explain?

Comment: @virolino The misuse of an older standard made Jonathan point out what happens . It is just pain and pain again to go backwards in time. One can spend _years_ pondering the old rules - but **why**? The rules have changed since then for very good reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So it is a thing of the old standards. I never used them, so I am safe :)

Comment: @virolino _"safe" said the basejumper_ :-) - Some implementations may let older shenaniganses pass, but you usually have options to turn these things into hard errors. I use _all_ I can find to keep myself somewhat inline.

Comment: @virolino — if you don't specify a type for an argument in the old non-prototype (aka K&R) notation, then it does default to `int` in C90: `main(argc, argv) char **argv; { … }`. C99 removed the 'implicit `int`' rules. In this code, the type of `scalar` is specified as `float`. See also C11 [§6.5.2.2 Function calls ¶6ff](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6).  It's hard to follow, but does discuss what happens.  See also [§6.7.6.3 Function declarators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3) and [§6.9.1 Function definitions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1).

Comment: What I'm not following here is why it ignores the declaration `Vector2_t Graphics_vec2_scalar_fmul(Vector2_t, float);` entirely - does it always do that if the function definition is non-prototype format?

Comment: Somewhat relevant parts seem to be C17 6.7.6 (is this the correct part?) "If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list, both shall agree in the number of parameters, and the type of each prototype parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument promotions to the
type of the corresponding identifier."  Default argument promotion meaning float turns into doubles.

Comment: @Lundin — the compiler is not ignoring the function prototype; it is objecting to the type conflict between the prototype declaration and the non-prototype definition.

Comment: Yeah but I was wondering why it would promote anything since we explicitly typed float in both declaration and definition. But apparently these old time definitions come with default argument promotion no matter what.

Comment: @Lundin — in pre-standard C, all floating-point arguments were passed as `double`, and if the function definition said `float parameter;` then the `double` value passed in was converted to `float`.  In practice, `float` was seldom used for single-value parameters; only `float` pointers were relevant, and then there was no conversion. Of course, in pre-standard C, all floating-point arithmetic was done using `double`, too.  As I tried to explain, the function definition used a `double` as the actual parameter, and that was converted to a `float` inside the function.

Comment: Your quote comes from [§6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes) ¶15](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p15).  Yes, the verbiage about "the type of each prototype parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument promotions" means that if the definition uses non-prototype notation, the prototype declaration must specify the types resulting from 'default argument promotions'.  In the code, the prototype declaration requires the function definition to use prototype notation, too, because of the use of `float`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you write the obsolete C "for fun". The obsolete C did not have prototypes at all, therefore the correct way to *declare* and *define* the function is to write

```
Vector2_t Graphics_vec2_scalar_fmul();

Vector2_t Graphics_vec2_scalar_fmul(a, scalar)
    Vector2_t a;
    float scalar;
{
    …
}
```

and the compiler will not do any parameter checking whatsoever. Have fun.

---

Other than that, the C18 standard says for the compatibility of functions that

> If **one type has a parameter type list** and **the other type is specified by a function definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list**, both shall agree in the number of parameters, and the **type of each prototype parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument promotions to the type of the corresponding identifier.** (In the determination of type compatibility and of a composite type, each parameter declared with function or array type is taken as having the adjusted type and each parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared type.)

Since `float` is promoted to `double` in the default argument promotions, **you can't declare a prototype for a function that has `float` parameters in the old style identifier list format.**

Answer (score 1):

> I do know that this is happening because no type is specified for the type initially, so the compiler assumes int and then throws the pedantic error.

No, this is not correct. Ancient C did default to `int` for variables declared without a type, but that is not what is happening here.

In ancient C, function declarations did not include the types of their parameters. When a function was called, any `char` or `short` argument was automatically converted to an `int` and passed to the function as that `int`. Any `float` argument was automatically converted to `double` and passed to the function as that `double`.

This means that when you define a function using the old grammar, such as:

```
Vector2_t Graphics_vec2_scalar_fmul(a, scalar)
    Vector2_t a;
    float scalar;
{ … }
```

you are saying the second argument is actually passed as a `double`. This conflicts with your declaration using the new grammar, which says the second argument is a `float`:

```
Vector2_t Graphics_vec2_scalar_fmul(Vector2_t, float);
```

Unless you are working with old code and need to retain source-code compatibility to keep some legacy system working, you should never use the old grammar. Always declare parameter types in the parentheses of the function declaration:

```
Vector2_t Graphics_vec2_scalar_fmul(Vector2_t a, float scalar)
{
    a.x *= scalar;
    a.y *= scalar;

    return a;
}
```